# How to connect Sequencial Search to an array and Main Menu

Tags: java

I am trying to connect the sequential search function to the menu so that it accepts user input and search the tp arrays in `apartA()` and `apartB()`. And also how can we connect the report function to the values in Functions `apartA()` and `apartB()`.

```
package jachi;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Jachi {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        menu();
    }

    public static void menu(){

        int j,k,choice;


        System.out.println("Menu");
        System.out.println("1. Register");
        System.out.println("2. Update");
        System.out.println("3. Report");
        System.out.println("4. Search");

        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        choice=scan.nextInt();

        switch(choice) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("Select Apartment type");
                System.out.println("1. Apartment A");
                System.out.println("2. Apartment B.");
                choice=scan.nextInt();

                if (choice==1)
                {
                    apartA();
                }
                else if (choice==2)
                {
                    apartB();
                }
                break;

            case 2:
                System.out.println("Update the student information");
                break;

            case 3:
                System.out.println("Rooms Available");
                report();
                break;

            case 4:
                System.out.print("Search for student. Please enter the TP number:");
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Incorrect input");
        }
    }

    public static int apartA()
    {     
        final int a = 9;


        //Normal Rooms Arrays
        int[] tp;
        tp = new int[a];

        String[] stname;
        stname = new String[a];

        String[] mob;
        mob = new String[a];

        int ttt = get.nextInt();
        int test = sequencialSearch(ttt);

        Scanner get = new Scanner(System.in);


        //Data Entry
        for (int index = 0; index < a; index++)
            {
            System.out.println("Student Information");

            System.out.println("Enter the student TP NUMBER:");
            tp[index] = get.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Enter the STUDENT NAME:");
            stname[index] = get.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter the MOBILE NUMBER:");
            mob[index] = get.nextLine();

            rent();
        }

        System.out.println("Rooms Full");

        /**Report Data, Test for Data presence
        *for(a=0;a<=2;a++)
        *{
        *System.out.println("TP NUMBER: "+tp[a]+"\t NAME: "+stname[a]+"\t MOBILE: "+mob[a]);
        *}*/
        return a;
    }

    public static void apartB(){

        System.out.println("Select Room Type");
        System.out.println("\t1. Normal Room");
        System.out.println("\t2. Master Room");

        int choice;
        final int j = 6;
        final int k = 3;

        Scanner get = new Scanner(System.in);
        choice = get.nextInt();
        Scanner get1 = new Scanner(System.in);

    if (choice==1) 
    {
            System.out.println("1. Normal Bedroom");

                // Normal Bedroom Arrays
                String[] tp;
                tp = new String[j];

                String[] stname;
                stname = new String[j];

                String[] mob;
                mob = new String[j];

                //Data Entry
                for (int index = 0; index < j; index++)
                    {
                    System.out.println("Student Information");

                    System.out.println("Enter the student TP NUMBER:");
                    tp[index] = get1.nextLine();

                    System.out.println("Enter the STUDENT NAME:");
                    stname[index] = get1.nextLine();

                    System.out.println("Enter the MOBILE NUMBER:");
                    mob[index] = get1.nextLine();

                    rent();
                    }

                    if(j<=5)
                    {
                    menu();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.println("All Houses Full");
                    }

    }

    else if (choice==2)
    {
            System.out.println("Master bedroon");

                //Master Bedroom Arrays
                String[] mastertp;
                mastertp = new String[k];

                String[] mastername;
                mastername = new String[k];

                String[] mastermob;
                mastermob = new String[k];


                //Data Entry
                for (int index = 0; index < k; index++)
                    {
                    System.out.println("Student Information");



                    System.out.println("Enter the student TP NUMBER:");
                    mastertp[index] = get1.nextLine();

                    System.out.println("Enter the STUDENT NAME:");
                    mastername[index] = get1.nextLine();

                    System.out.println("Enter the MOBILE NUMBER:");
                    mastermob[index] = get1.nextLine();

                    int x,y,z,pay;
                    x=100;
                    pay=300;
                    y=3*pay;
                    z=x+y;


                    System.out.println("Charges to be Paid");
                    System.out.println("Charges                 Amount");
                    System.out.println("Utilities charge:       rm100");
                    System.out.println("Three month rental:     rm"+y);
                    System.out.println("Total:                  rm"+z);
                    menu();
                }

                System.out.println("Full House Man");
    }
}

    public static void rent(){
        int x,y,z,pay;
        x=100;
        pay=300;
        y=3*pay;
        z=x+y;


        System.out.println("Charges to be Paid");
        System.out.println("Charges                 Amount");
        System.out.println("Utilities charge:       rm100");
        System.out.println("Three month rental:     rm"+y);
        System.out.println("Total:                  rm"+z);
        menu();
    } 

    public static void report(){

        int x,y,z;
        x=0;
        y=x+1;
        z=6-y;

        System.out.println("Rooms occupied; "+y);
        System.out.println("Rooms available; "+z);

        menu();
    }

    public static int sequencialSearch(int Tnumbr){
        int index,
            element;
        boolean found;

        index = 0;
        element = 0;
        found = false;

        while(!found && index == Tnumbr){
         /* if(array[index] == 9{
          * found = true;
          * element = index;
          * }
          * index++;
         */

        }

    return element;
}
}
```

Comment: Where is the SRS of your project ? IMHO , you should make the question more clear.

Comment: the title of the question is misleading, you might want to change that.

Comment: Map<String, Integer> nameToValueMap have u heard this???

Comment: @senthilPrabhu sorry i havent, i am new to java programming...this is my first program

Comment: @Yash has answered it seems..!

Comment: @farouktukur: You can also have generic method.. Look into tat also.. Which ever fits u can use it..!

Answer (score 0):

Ok that is a lot of code, lets try breaking it into simpler classes.
first would be Apartment. Lets have a class for apartment and put all the utility methods like report() and search() into it.

The apartment class can be something like:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;



class Apartment{

    /** Integer: roomid, String StrudentId  **/
    HashMap<Integer, String> rooms = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

    public Apartment(){

    }

    public Integer sequentialSearch(String tpNumber){
    /** Returns null if student is absent **/
    for(Integer roomId : rooms.keySet())
    {
        if(tpNumber.equals(rooms.get(roomId)))
            return roomId;
    }

    return null;
}


public void report(){
    System.out.println("ROOM_NUM\tSTUDENT_ID");
    for(Integer roomId : rooms.keySet())
    {
        System.out.println(roomId +"\t" + rooms.get(roomId));
    }
}
}
```

Now in your Main class Jachi you can create and use the apartments like:

```
Apartment apartA = new Apartment();
apartA.sequentialSearch("SOME_STUDENTID_HERE");
apartA.report();

Apartment apartB = new Apartment();
apartB.sequentialSearch("SOME_STUDENTID_HERE");
apartB.report();
```

You can also create Arrays of apartments now. Rest is left for you to explore.